# how do you embed an interactive Google Map on a GAS standalone app?

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

I want to create a GAS standalone web app that will have a google map embedded. Visitors will see their location, drag around and will be able to pin details that can be seen by other users. User clicks on a point, a custom form pops, they fill and submit for admin approval. Can we make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, now it is impossible to implement an application required by you neither using the [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp) nor [Html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) Services. The `Ui Service` can produce only static map bitmaps without ability to drag/scroll, zoom, markers selection, etc. And the `Html Service` cannot correctly handle the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) because the [Caja sanitizer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja), at least, complains once trying to compile any [Maps API Sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) by outputting the `FATAL_ERROR js?sensor=false:13+3 - 15+4: Properties cannot end in "__": Rule "setBadSuffix",...` message. There is a [proper feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1447) on the Issue Tracker. Please star it to promote this topic to the developers.

Comment: Thanks, very informative, any work-around idea, coz i wanna create a super-handy app based on a map with crowd-sourced info. I know GAS, javascript and html

Answer (score 2):

Maps support is planned for HTML service. Stay tuned.

Comment: Wow! Glad to see you @Corey, can you whisper to me how soon it may be out coz i got an idea for a very handy app based on a map with  crowdsourced info... and do you think my idea is totally possible?

Comment: I can't promise times; I will just say that if you are interested in the status of google apis like maps inside of HtmlService, keep an eye on the open source Caja project, and that will give you a sense of where we are headed

Comment: for example an interactive map, user pins a post then  others can see and comment 1. do you think my idea is achievable 2. how much time do you think it may take me (intermediary) and what way would you advice me to go about it?

Comment: Those aren't questions that I'm really equipped to answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is still not supported. Same error is returned for html service. The issue occurs as soon as you try to include the Maps API with:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
</script>
```